# R x axis date label only one value

Tags: r, graph, plot

I'm creating a plot in R with dates as the xaxis. My frame has dates, no problem. I'm using  custom date range - one that cuts off some of the earliest data by using a fixed start and extend slightly past the latest data by using a end determined by some other code. The range is ~47 days right now. That's all working fine.

My problem is that the xaxis label includes only a single label, "Feb" but I'd like to include at least 3 labels, if not 5.

```
starttime <- strptime("20110110", "%Y%m%d")
endtime <- strptime("20110226 1202", "%Y%m%d %H%M") #This is actually determined programmatically, but that's not important
xrange <- c(starttime, endtime)
yrange <- c(0, 100)
par(mar=par()$mar+c(0,0,0,7),bty="l")
plot(xrange, yrange, type="n", xlab="Submission Time", ylab="Best Score", main="Top Scores for each team over time")
#More code to loop and add a bunch of lines(), but it's not really relevant
```

The resulting graph looks like this:
[image]

I really just want better labels. I'm not too concerned about exactly what they are, but something with Month + Day, and at least 3 of them.

Comment: Ok, it seems like axis(1) or axTicks(1) might do it somewhat automatically. I just need to figure out how to change it from the scientific notation that it wants to use into something like "Feb 26"...

Comment: Also you might want to consider looking at `matplot(..., type='s')`, instead of using an empty `plot()` followed by individual calls to `lines()`.

Comment: Thanks for this question as it answered mine: Using a dummy plot call to set the limits is the only way I've found that works with date ranges / temporal data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.  I changed your plot() statement a little and added two lines.

```
 starttime <- strptime("20110110", "%Y%m%d")
 endtime <- strptime("20110226 1202", "%Y%m%d %H%M")
 #This is actually determined programmatically, but that's not important
 xrange <- c(starttime, endtime)
 yrange <- c(0, 100)
 par(mar=par()$mar+c(0,0,0,7),bty="l")

 #I added xaxt="n" to supress the plotting of the x-axis
 plot(xrange, yrange, type="n", xaxt="n", xlab="Submission Time", ylab="Best Score", main="Top Scores for each team over time")

 #I added the following two lines to plot the x-axis with a label every 7 days
 atx <- seq(starttime, endtime, by=7*24*60*60)
 axis(1, at=atx, labels=format(atx, "%b\n%d"), padj=0.5)

 #More code to loop and add a bunch of lines(), but it's not really relevant
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I may use something like `by=(endtime-starttime)/4` to generate 5 evenly distributed points, no matter how large it is. That'll scale better for when it's 147 days instead of 47 days.

Comment: Just use the `len=N` argument to get `N` points---`seq()` can already do what you approximate here.

Answer (score 3):

In addition, look at `axis.Date()`, which is **not** an S3 generic, but can help set up the extra labels you want. I wrote a patch for this function that got incorporated several R versions ago, which allowed axes without labels. Here is an example taken from `?axis.Date`:

```
random.dates <- as.Date("2001/1/1") + 70*sort(stats::runif(100))
plot(random.dates, 1:100)
# or for a better axis labelling
plot(random.dates, 1:100, xaxt="n")
axis.Date(1, at=seq(as.Date("2001/1/1"), max(random.dates)+6, "weeks"))
axis.Date(1, at=seq(as.Date("2001/1/1"), max(random.dates)+6, "days"),
          labels = FALSE, tcl = -0.2)
```

which produces:
[image]

There is also `Axis.Date()` which **is** an S3 generic, so can be called via `Axis(dates.vec, ....)` where `dates.vec` is the x-axis vector of dates. `at` etc can also be specified.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by hand if you suppress the x-axis annotation in the call to `plot()` and then use `axis()` with manually specified points and labels:

```
axis(1,at=axis.pos[axis.ind],labels=axis.txt[axis.ind])
```

using a set of indices `axis.ind` which selects from x values and formatted labels. You can use `strftime()` for just about anything, eg `'%d %b'` should produce day and human-readable short months as in

```
R> strftime(Sys.Date(), "%d %b")
[1] "26 Feb"
```

Comment: This seems like a good path, but I'm unclear on what I'd use for the values. Would I just select my starting and ending dates, then get the midpoint date? So it would be commands like `axis(1, at=starttime, labels=strftime(starttime, "%d %b"))`?

Comment: You need to figure that out. Axis labeling is *hard*. You caught the default behaviour at a suboptimal outcome, now you either need to live with it, or write yourself a little alternative or try to parameterize the default differently.  Maybe setting explicit `xlim` limits will help.  We can't tell as you supplied no (mock) data to make this reproducible.

Comment: I know it's hard - that's why I'm asking for help! If it was easy I would have figured it out.  I supplied the exact code to generate the axis, as it looks in my example. The lines aren't relevant to the problem. If you run the code I gave in the question you'll get that same graph with no lines, perfectly fine for this purpose.